# Save input data from user to my own file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage with text area. I populate this area with a text file of my own, so the user sees the text when they load the page. I want the user to be able to edit the text in this area and they will click 'save'. This will save to MY file, so that the next time someone opens the page they will get the text that the previous user wrote.

I have been looking for quite a while and cannot find what I need. Some things I found said suggest maybe some php (would prefer not). But I  have yet to find a source that describes this exact situation.

Here is some of my HTML code:

```
<div class="emailEditor">
        <label for="emailEditBox" class="col-2 col-form-label">Email Editor</label>
        <div class="col-10">
            <textarea style = "min-height: 300px;" class="form-control" rows="5" id="emailEditBox"></textarea>
        </div>

        <button id="loadEmail" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="loadFile()">Load</button>
        <button id="saveEmail" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="saveFile()">Save</button>
        <button id="previewEmail" type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="previewFile()">Preview</button>
    </div>

<div class="emailPreview">
        <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Email Preview</label>
        <div class="emailOutput">
             <!--Preview here (rendered output of the html file)-->
        </div>
</div>
```

Here is some of my Javascript and Jquery:

```
<script>
    function loadFile() {
        var reader = new XMLHttpRequest();
        reader.open('GET', "EmailTemplate.html", false);
        reader.send();
        var text = reader.responseText;
        document.getElementById("emailEditBox").value = text;
    }

    function writeFile() {

    }
</script>

<script>
    $(function previewFile(){
        $(".emailOutput").load("EmailTemplate.html");
    });
</script>
```

The load and preview part are working, but I cannot find a way to save the file.

Comment: Something on the server has to update that file you are getting the text from.  PHP is one option to do that.

Comment: You need to send a POST or PUT to your backend with the text the user entered and save that as the file that gets read.

Comment: It would require serverside code to save it.... you can not just update the file from the browser.... that would be scary.

Comment: As other commentators have said, there's no way to save to a file system on the client side because that would be crazy bad for security.

Comment: @epascarello It's just for a demo that I'm using for something else completely, don't worry about security.

Comment: You can not just save a file without code that runs on the server that updates the file.

Answer (score 1):

You need server side processing that will receive the data, and then use POST Request to send data to the server. On server-side, you can use for example Node.js if you want a solution in pure JS or use simple old school PHP.